# PHP strange results, the floating point is not the issue

Tags: php

I really don't understand why two same inputs give 2 different results. Can anyone tell me why this:

```
$t=0;
$c=0;
$p = 151000;
    while ($t<=144) {
        if ($t%12 == 0) {
            $p = $p*(1 -((1 + 0.00833333333) ** $t - 1)/((1 + 0.00833333333) ** 144 - 1));

            echo "<br>".$c."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; .round($p);
            $c = $c+1;
        }
        $t = $t+1;
    }
}
```

when `$t` is `24` the result is : `130347`

but when I write JUST TO CHECK THE RESULT: `$p = $p*(1 -((1 + 0.00833333333) ** 24 - 1)/((1 + 0.00833333333) ** 144 - 1));`

the result is: `136554`

Two identical values give two different results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you replace `$t` with `24`, `$t = $t + 1` no longer affectes anything.

Comment: They are completely different situations I am talking about the results which should be the same and they are not.